# multipart/form-data with both files and text-based form data in App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I am trying to build a small app that will take a `multipart/form-data` to send a form with two data items:

1. username - a text field
2. file - an image file

The app blocks are attached in the picture to this mail. **I do not know how to send `multipart/form-data` with both files and text-based form data.** Need your suggestions on this. Can you please help?

For those who are not acquainted with the Content-Type=multipart/form data, here is a one liner about it:

> The content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient
>   for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing
>   non-ASCII characters. The content type "multipart/form-data" should be
>   used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and
>   binary data.

More details can be found in:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls

I have found ways to achieve it using get and put methods. I would want to achieve this using the `Post` method.

## The php server code is:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$user = $_POST["username"];
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Upload failed with reason = $uploadFailureReason <br>";
}
else {
    echo "Upload Sucessful <br>";
    $pyscript = '/home/ubuntu/workdir/src/httppython.py';
    $python = '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python';
    $filePath = $target_file;
    $cmd = "$python $pyscript --image $filePath --user $user";
    //echo "command = $cmd    ";
    exec("$cmd", $output);
    echo "<input type=button onClick=\"location.href='upload_new.html'\" value='New Upload'>"
}

?>
```

Comment: as already said in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/uCJjFPbv3vg/41P-Rp5XAQAJ), **`multipart/formdata` is not supported in App Inventor**, you only can upload a file OR some data at the same time... sorry...